# May I add a table view in a view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 2 controllers.

I want to add a table view in the view controller,
and the table view's cell has the custom class of `tableviewcell`.

I tried to use `[self addsubview:(the controller.view)` into the controller.

I can see the list, but cannot set each cell's value.

In my viewcontroller:

```
 TableViewController *viewController = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
[self addChildViewController:viewController];
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
[viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

I try to init the tableviewcontroller in my viewcontroller. Now i can see the tableview. But i cannot set the value of each cell. even more the break point cannot stop in the 
 `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: What is your `tableView`'s `dataSource` property set to?

Comment: do you want to add custom cell in tableview???

Comment: What is "the controller"? Is it a tableView or a tableviewcontroller?  It should be a tableView and then you wouldn't add the .view - just add the UiTableview instance

Comment: write some code so we understand exactly what's your problem!\

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to provide a delegate and a data source for your table view, and implement the required methods.  I have a strong suspicion you skipped a couple crucial steps here.  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will never get called unless your view controller is properly set up as the UITableView's delegate and data source.

See the [UITableView programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html) for more info.